# Using boost::lexical_cast<double>(string)

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

I am a beginner and need an explanation as to why this doesn't work:

```
string myArray[620223];
//myArray is then populated with a while loop using ifstream and getline
string myString = myArray[9];
double myValue;

try {
    myValue = boost::lexical_cast<double>(myString);
} 
catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast const&) {
    myValue = 0;
}
```

myArray[9] is non-zero but the resulting double is always zero. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is `myArray`? An array of `std::string`s? What do you get when you just output `myString`?

Comment: Yes. The output of myString is the correct value. For example, cout gives: 9.968750.

Comment: Something funny is going on.  Your code is correct.  There's an important detail somewhere that's not being exposed in the question.

Comment: What is `myArray`?  Can you show the declaration?

Comment: My thoughts as well. I'm using Xcode 3.1.3. I don't know if this is problematic.
 string myArray[620223];

Comment: @user1830888 just update the question with the *declaration* of `myArray`.  We want to know its type, since it's not mentioned.

Comment: The code as given is fine. Try either (1) producing a [sscce](http://sscce.org) or (2) using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Since the code appears fine, here's an educated guess. `myArray[9]` is the *tenth* array element. `myArray[0]` is the first. You actually wanted the ninth element, `myArray[8]`.